# Calling JSON file into ansible playbook when running playbook locally

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

Trying to run a playbook locally with some variables such as username,password and IP.

Want to store them locally on my machine and call into playbook.How can we do it?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  name:login
  vars:
    hostname: 
    username: 
    password:
```

How do i pass these variable into the playbook

```
{
  "login": [
    {
      "hostname": "19.15.16.17",
      "username": "admin",
      "password":"askcnascn"

    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html). This allows you to store your variables inside a file and load them in a playbook using the syntax:

```
- include_vars:
    file: vars.yaml
    name: vars
```

Comment: where do place this vars.yaml/vars.json in the local system?

Comment: In the same place as the executing playbook.

Comment: can you please refer the json file and how i refer that into playbook

Comment: Any more suggestion?